# What is the relation between Spring @Transactional and Spring @Lock annotation?

Tags: java, spring, java-annotations

I found that the `@Transactional` is used to ensure transaction on repository method or on a service method.
`@Lock` is used on repository method to ensure locking of entity to provide isolation.

Some questions are raised in my mind:

> 1. What are major difference/relations in these two annotations ?
> 2. When to use `@Transactional` and when to use `@Lock` ?
> 3. Is `@Lock` useful in distributed database system to provide data concurrency and consistency ?

Comment: `@Lock` is a Spring Data (JPA) annotation and not a Spring annation like the `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 21):

**Transactional:** Whenever you put @Transactional annotation, it enables transactional behavior  which qualifies ACID properties

> **ACID:** ACID (**Atomicity**, **Consistency**, **Isolation**, **Durability**) is a set of
>   properties of database transactions intended to guarantee the validity
>   even in the event of errors.

**Atomic**
Guarantees that all operations in a transaction are treated as a single “unit”, which either succeeds completely or fails completely.

**Consistent**
Ensures that a transaction can only bring the database from one valid state to another by preventing data corruption.

**Isolation**
Determines how and when changes made by one transaction become visible to the other. Serializable and Snapshot Isolation are the top 2 isolation levels from a strictness standpoint.

**Durable**
Ensures that the results of the transaction are permanently stored in the system. The modifications must persist even in case of power loss or system failures.

---

**Lock:** It should not be confused with transactional,@Lock enables locking behavior during a **transaction**

> JPA has two main lock types defined.
>
> 1. Pessimistic Locking
> 2. Optimistic Locking

If you want to know more about Pessimistic and Obtimistic locking you can explore  the internet, below is explanation from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks),

> **Pessimistic Locking** When we are using Pessimistic Locking in a
>   transaction and access an entity, it will be locked immediately. The
>   transaction releases the lock either by committing or rolling back the
>   transaction.
>
> **Optimistic Locking** In Optimistic Locking, the transaction doesn't lock
>   the entity immediately. Instead, the transaction commonly saves the
>   entity's state with a version number assigned to it.
>
> When we try to update the entity's state in a different transaction,
>   the transaction compares the saved version number with the existing
>   version number during an update.
>
> At this point, if the version number differs, it means that the entity
>   can't be modified. If there is an active transaction then that
>   transaction will be rolled back and the underlying JPA implementation
>   will throw an OptimisticLockException.
>
> Apart from the version number approach, we can use other approaches
>   such as timestamps, hash value computation, or serialized checksum,
>   depending on which approach is the most suitable for our current
>   development context.

***There are also other lock types available in spring***

- **NONE:** No lock.
- **OPTIMISTIC:** Optimistic lock.
- **OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT:** Optimistic lock, with version update.
- **PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT:** Pessimistic write lock, with version update
- **PESSIMISTIC_READ:** Pessimistic read lock.
- **PESSIMISTIC_WRITE:** Pessimistic write lock.
- **READ:** Synonymous with OPTIMISTIC.
- **WRITE:** Synonymous with OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT.

---

Now answer to your questions

1. What are the major differences/relations in these two annotations?

**You will understand after reading above**

2. When to use @Transactional and when to use @Lock?

**If you want transactional behavior then add @transactional and if your usecase requires locking and as per use case use appropriate locking**

3. Is @Lock useful in the distributed database system to provide data
   concurrency and consistency?

**The two main tools we use to cope with concurrency are database transactions and distributed locks. These two are not interchangeable. You can't use a transaction when you need a lock. You can't use a lock when you need a transaction.** [source](https://makandracards.com/makandra/31937-differences-between-transactions-and-locking)

Comment: can you be a bit more specific... I mean a what are the usual cases when a transaction can fail ? does transaction internally use any locking system ?

Comment: yes transactional locking happens to protect the resource and ensure ACID,  Isolation plays a role here too, and last committed  transaction wins,  by default connection's isolation level is READ COMMITTED, which protects against dirty read

Comment: you can read more about locking during transaction at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/dbms_concurrency_control.htm

Comment: You guys can check this post and help me out? I'm trying to implement according to this post but without success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351144/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress-on

Comment: This will add more context : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530115/spring-data-pessimistic-write-returns-old-db-value
gist : `@Lock` only works for that repository call and not the whole `@Transactional` method call