# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress on @Lock annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm facing an issue I've never experienced before.

I'm trying to use a `@Lock` on a `repository` Method to avoid concurrency issues and I'm getting the error described on the Title.

**DB Configuration -**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.sample.repositories"
)
public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PoolProperties properties = new PoolProperties();
        properties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        properties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(properties);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages("com.sample.domains")
                .persistenceUnit("persistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sampleHibernate.properties");

        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                            e -> e.getValue())
                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the flux of the application starts in a regular  controller, which have the following service autowired by builder..

**This is the service:**

```
@Service
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

   private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

   public SampleServiceImpl (SampleRepository sampleRepository) {
      this.sampleRepository= sampleRepository;
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void sampleMethod(String parameter1, String parameter2) {
      
      SampleObject sampleObject = sampleRepository.findSampleObjectByParameter1AndParameter2(parameter1, parameter2);
      System.out.println("SAMPLE REGISTRIE: " + sampleObject);
      sampleRepository.save(sampleObject.setUpdateDate(new Date()));

   }

}
```

And of course, this is the **repository**:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleObject, Long> {
   
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query(value = "SELECT so FROM SampleObject so WHERE so.parameter1 = ?1 AND so.parameter2 = ?2")
    SampleObject findSampleObjectByParameter1AndParameter2(String parameter1, String parameter2);

}
```

This is actually a very simple flux... but I'm getting the:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

And this is just calling the method of the repository with the `@Lock` annotation.. I don't get why, becase i'm ussing `@Transactional` annotations all over my application but is the first time using the lock.

Anyone can help me out?

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is the code where I call the method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/sample")
public class SampleController {

   private SampleService sampleService;

   public SampleController (SampleService sampleService) {
      this.sampleService = sampleService;
   }

   @GetMapping("/executeSample")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> executeSample(){
        sampleService.sampleMethod(parameter1, parameter2);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the complete stackTrace of the error!

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:419)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:525)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:140)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy205.sampleMethod(Unknown Source)
    at co.demo.sample.services.implementations.SampleServiceImpl.sampleMethod(SampleServiceImpl.java:436)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy266.executeSample(Unknown Source)
    at co.demo.sample.controllers.SampleController.executeSample(SampleController.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.checkTransaction(AbstractQueryImpl.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:526)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 110 more
2021-07-16 13:06:50.807 ERROR 22044 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.j.p.s.i.stock.StockServiceImpl         : Se ha producido un error en la carga de archivo masivo de Modificación de STOCK - PLR2, el mensaje es: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Comment: can you also put the code from where you are calling your impl method

Comment: @ShaileshChandra updated to show the caller code.

Comment: Please, can you provide the full error stack trace in your question?

Comment: @jccampanero updated to show full stak trace error.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel.

Comment: @DanielHenao I checked your configuration and everything works, could you please make a sample project where we can reproduce the problem?
Probably I had other hibernate properties or other spring boot version

Comment: @saver my Spring boot version is: 1.5.22.RELEASE, everything is related to it.. spring jpa and so on.. In terms of hibernate configuration, I have nothing very wierd... just the standards..

Comment: Why do you think pessimistic locking will resolve your concurrency issues? You can also configure Hibernate to throw an optimistic locking exception when a process try to update a record that has already been updated by a second process. Can you give more context why the concurrency issues happen?

Comment: @guicey yea, the concurrency in this method is not vry common, but i have to guarantee that if someone access a particular row and a second process is actually using that row, the second process don´t even read the row because it can show or update wrong data that has to be treated first by the first process. That's basicly the context.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start a transaction before executing a locking query. You can only lock something in the context of a database transaction.

You use `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` on non transactional context.

You need add @Transactional.

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Transactional
@Query(value = "SELECT so FROM SampleObject so WHERE so.parameter1 = ?1 AND so.parameter2 = ?2")
SampleObject findSampleObjectByParameter1AndParameter2(String parameter1, String parameter2);
```

and yet would be interesting put de `propagation` with `Propagation.NESTED`, to nest on transaction created at the service layer.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
```

Comment: so you're saying that I need to add the `@Transactional` in the service and on the repository in order this to work?

Comment: In this case, just the annotated repository is enough. But imagine, that you have 2 command calls to the repository, on sampleMethod, and you need control whether 2 transaction was done, in this case you need annotate the service to create a transaction in service with repository methods annotated with @Transactional, because the service will create the transaction and the repository transactions will be nested to the service transactions.

Answer (score 0):

use @Transactional annotation. it should get resolved

```
    public interface SampleRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<SampleObject,Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT so FROM SampleObject so WHERE so.parameter1 = 
    ?1 AND so.parameter2 = ?2")
    SampleObject findSampleObjectByParameter1AndParameter2(String 
    parameter1, String parameter2);

}
```

Comment: The whole purpose of the @Lock is to actual lock the other Threads to modify the same records, I think if I add `@Transactional` on the repository... any other thread could access the row.. Am I Wrong?